# Get an unique id for a connected network device

Tags: java, sockets, networking, mac-address

I am connected to a WLAN, where a special hardware device is connected to as well. I communicate to that device via a socket, since I know its IP.

Is there a was to identify that hardware device in the network by an id? I found out in Java it is not possible to obtain the MAC-address of a connected device. Is there any other alternative?

Thanks,
best regards

Comment: You state that you already known the device's IP. What further identification do you need? Please clarify.

Comment: The devices IP is not unique. The problem is that the programm saves the ips. And if a different device connects and has the same IP as my device before I have to be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: Do you have any control over the software that runs on the device?

Comment: It is a special hardware device on which software I have no control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mac addresses should be unique. Maybe you can get needed information from the ARP table.
Command "arp -a" works on Windows and Linux.

But there is a problems:

1. This is not portable way
2. The ARP table is quite variable
3. If the device is behind a router, then this does not work.

Comment: Thank you, parsing the console in Java does it!

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can call [NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) that will return hardware MAC address

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNicList = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(enumNicList.hasMoreElements())
{
    NetworkInterface oNic = enumNicList.nextElement();
    byte[] baMacAddress = oNic.getHardwareAddress();
    String sMacAddress = new BigInteger(1, baMacAddress).toString(16);
    System.out.println(sMacAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any control of the responses of the device, and the device doesn't contain any identifying API calls and such, then just use the IP address and make that IP statically assigned to that device via your router. Then you can either create your own table of IP <-> device list, or even scrape the IP table off your router.

Come to think of it, you could probably get the MAC address the same way - scrape the DHCP table off your router's configuration screen.

Comment: As written above the IP is not unique, since a device does not always have the same IP - eg after a reconnect of the device or even in another routers network. I want to finde out a unique device identification in Java on runtime.

Comment: So then I assume you cannot access the router in this network? If you have no control over the device and its application, and it doesn't send any identifiable information, and it has no identifying APIs, and how it queries your application has no unique characteristics, then you are out of luck.

Comment: In some cases there may be control on the router. But anyway the application shall determine the MAC-address/id on runtime.